# Svg Images drawing speed

Tags: browser, svg

I need to know how to optimize images in svg.

Which is faster in drawing svg:
1- Embed the image in the svg file as base64 string.
2- Or add the images as Url.

Comment: The answer to all these types of questions is "try it and see".  The only truely accurate answer will be dependent on your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding the base64 of the image will send all the data in a single connection to the HTTP server. So it might be faster that using an URL to a different document.

But using an URL you will benefit of browser caching (you can even force loading the image beforehand).